# Redis session provider not working on Azure PaaS webapp

Tags: azure, session-state, redis

I am working on a Sitecore 9 solution which is hosted on Azure PaaS.

I have a simple piece of code that is meant to store an object in session which works fine on my local machine but once deployed to the Azure WebApp I get below exception:

```
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: mscorlib
  at System.Object.GetType()
  at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.Eval(String script, String[] keyArgs, Object[] valueArgs)
  at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisConnectionWrapper.TryUpdateAndReleaseLockIfLockIdMatch(String sessionId, Object lockId, ISessionStateItemCollection data, Int32 sessionTimeout)
  at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem)
  at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

[image]

Has someone faced a similar issue in past and has an idea what needs to be done to fix it?

Regards,
Pratik Thakker

Comment: I haven't had a similar issue, but can you use the FTP for the Azure site and see if your code files you are expecting are all there? I have seen some things not get deployed and errors you would normally get locally look different in Azure.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @RReilley. I did check the code files on the server and it seems to have all the expected files.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of at the moment is to check if your object is serializable? Or try to set redis in config on your local machine and test.